# Sorting 2 arrays side by side

Tags: vb.net, arrays, sorting

Basicly I have a program that retrieves data and parses it, which is fine, so it starts from:

11:981.8 which equals to November 981.8 now what I have done is split the "November" and the "981.8" into 2 different arrays, with other similar data, now what I need to be able to do, is sort the array in either Ascending or Descending order, however keeping in tact, the November and 981.8 side by side in a list box.

My current code is:

```
Private Sub sortData(ByVal strYear As String, ByVal strSort As String)
    lbDispData.Items.Clear()

    Dim strData As String = My.Settings.usage2011
    Dim arrRawData() As String
    Dim arrMonth As New ArrayList
    Dim arrKilo As New ArrayList

        arrRawData = strData.Split("_")

        For Each strUsage As String In arrRawData
            Dim arrSmall As String()
            arrSmall = strUsage.Split(":")
            arrSmall(0) = MonthName(arrSmall(0))

            arrMonth.Add(arrSmall(0))
            arrKilo.Add(arrSmall(1))
        Next

        If strSort = 0 Then
            'Sort in ascending order
        ElseIf strSort = 1 Then
            'Sort in descending order
        End If
End Sub
```

Or If possible is there a better way?

EDIT: Just to mention, there are many more values, not just November and 981.8, there would be for example December and 128.1, January and 191.1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use two arrays. Use one array or [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), and each item in the array should be either an instance of a custom Class which would have Month and Kilo properties, or a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) instance.

Then you can sort by whichever property you want, and don't have to worry about related information staying together.

To create a Tuple for an item, you use Tuple.Create:

```
Dim myTuple = Tuple.Create(monthValue, kiloValue)
```

Then you can access values from the Tuple using Item1, Item2, etc.

```
Dim month = myTuple.Item1
Dim kilo = myTuple.Item2
```

Comment: Ive never used Tuple's before, how would I implement it into my code, or maybe an example if possible of adding to a tuple and also sorting it, thanks.

Comment: So do Tuples store multiple values? so if I did a For Each Item in Array and created a tuple inside it, it would create a tuple for each of the items? EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention in my original question, there is one set of values for each month, so 2 x 12.

Comment: A Tuple represents one item composed of two values in this case (month, kilo). If you have one pair of values for each month, you would have an Array containing 12 Tuples.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two ways to store this kind of data: array of structures, or structure of arrays. Your implementation, at present, is the latter. As you suspect, the former is typically preferred in languages which provide access to objects and user-defined types.

To solve this problem using an array-of-structures data representation, you will define your own type - for instance, you could call it MonthFloatPair or something more relevant to your application, or you could simply use a built-in type that suits your needs - and have a single array of type MonthFloatPair. To add a MonthFloatPair, you'd parse a string exactly as you are now, and then simply assign the month to one member of MonthFloatPair and the number (Kilo?) to another. Then all you would have to do is to write a method to provide an ordering comparison of MonthFloatPair objects (I believe this is possible in vb.net, at any rate), and then sort this array normally however you'd like.

To solve this problem using a structure-of-arrays data representation, you do exactly what you're doing now. To sort, sort normally as you would for the array you're sorting on, with one caveat: every time you change the position of an element of the array on which you're basing the sorting (e.g., by exchanging in O(n^2) sorts, or placing into a new array as in MergeSort), you need to move the corresponding (same index) element in the other array in the same manner.